# C++ static_cast downcast validity

Tags: c++

Is this `static_cast` downcast valid?

```
// non-virtual, may be non-trivially copyable
struct Base{
    int m_object;
};

// Derived class have only non-virtual functions
struct A : Base{
    void arggh(){
        std::cout << "Arrghh " << m_object;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base base{190};
    A& a = static_cast<A&>(base);
    a.arggh();
    return 0;
}
```

I mean, CREATE base class, and then cast to derived.

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b41fa256a292b145)

Comment: No, an object of type `Base` is not an object of type `A`

Comment: just curious, why would you do this?

Comment: You should do the invert Base* b = new A(); and all the methods that you have that are common should be "virtual". That is how you handle it, that is the reason to have a interface that specifies the contract.

Comment: @miradham Wel...... I found myself in situation where I start writing Proxy object, which I could easily recreate(it have only 1 ptr). Then I need Proxy + some data...  And then I thought what a heck... :) Hard to explain in two words.

Comment: @appleapple not exactly - this is non-virtual classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`static_cast` for performing downcast does not perform any safety checks. Since it's possible for a `Base&` to be referencing an instance of `A`, the cast proceeds and since it's *NOT* actually referencing an `A`, we enter undefined behavior territory<sup>*</sup>.

A `dynamic_cast` on the other hand is safer. It will perform a check and throw an exception in the case of reference casting, or return `nullptr` in the case of pointer casting<sup>†</sup>.

However, since your base class lacks any virtual functions, `dynamic_cast` is impossible, so you'd need to modify it with at least a virtual destructor:

```
class Base{
public:
    int m_object;
    virtual ~Base()=default;
};
```

Now if we tried to cast:

```
A* a = dynamic_cast<A*>(&base);
if (a)
    a->arggh();
else
    std::cout << "null\n";
```

Our output would be

> null

---

<sup>*</sup>Relevant standardese can be found in [expr.static.cast]:

> [for a cast like `static_cast<D&>(b)` where `b` is an instance of a base class for `D`], If the object of type “*cv1* `B`” is actually a base class subobject of an object of type `D`, the result refers to the enclosing object of type `D`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

<sup>†</sup>Relevant standardese at [expr.dynamic.cast]

> The value of a failed cast to pointer type is the null pointer value of the required result type. A failed cast to reference type throws an exception of a type that would match a handler of type
>   `std::bad_cast`

Comment: Note that adding virtual member function and performing a dynamic_cast has a performance cost.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Not all `Base` objects are of type `A`<sup>1</sup>, although the converse is true, and a `static_cast` would work in *that* direction.

---

<sup>1</sup>Another translation unit might have a class that inherits from `Base`.

Comment: But derived classes "empty", zero-sized, non-virtual http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea14a7cd238064e1

Comment: @tower120: That's UB.

Comment: @tower120 congratulations, you hit the worst kind of UB: "But it works right now on ths machine on this invocation of the program!" one.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I actually think it will works everywhere now (it have zero offsets)... But UB is UB.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all.

Let's say Base is represented in memory by this block [--] and A is [--+], here you can see that A contains a part Base (with the little '-').

When you are creating a Base you have your [--] and then you are casting it to A which means that you are saying it's in fact [--+] BUT the memory after [--] does not correspond to [--+]

As you may understand with this example, you can cast A to Base because [--+] contains [--]