# Does this downcasting lead to undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, downcast, static-cast

Given this sample:

```
  class Base
  {
      public:
      void foo() {}; 
  };

  class Derived : public Base
  {     
  };

  int main()
  {
      Base b;
      Derived* d = static_cast<Derived*>(&b);
      d->foo();
  }
```

I just have three cases: when `void foo()`:

- is member of `Base`,
- and when it is member of `Derived`,
- and when it is member of `Base` and `Derived`.

My questions are:

- Does the member access expression `d->foo()` is undefined behavior in all three cases?.
- If the member access expression is UB, Does the only workaround is to use `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310700/c-static-cast-downcast-validity

Comment: note that `foo` is a member of both `Base` and `Derived` in your example. Derived classes inherit their parents' members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the C++ standard §7.6.1.9.11](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#11)

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `B`”, where `B` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv2* `D`”, where `D` is a complete class derived from `B`,
>
> ...
>
> If the prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `B`” points to a `B` that is actually a base class subobject of an object of type `D`, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type `D`.
> Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So using `static_cast` to downcast is only valid if you know (via some other means) that the cast is valid. If you take a `Base` that *isn't* a `Derived` and use a `static_cast` to pretend that it is, you've invoked undefined behavior, even before you try to dereference the pointer. So you could remove the `d->foo()` line and *still* have undefined behavior. It's the cast that's bad.

If your goal is to conditionally check whether you've got an instance of a subclass, then you want `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: *"So you could remove the d->foo() line and still have undefined behavior"*. does that's mean this expression `static_cast<Derived*>(&b);` yields UB?

Comment: Yes. The `static_cast` line yields undefined behavior. You're casting a value to a type that it doesn't belong to, and you're using a cast that effectively asserts it's safe without checking.

Comment: .. and then dereferencing the pointer `d` yields UB, regardless of what the member it tries to access?

Comment: Worse than that. [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) propagates forward and backward in your code, so as long as that line *exists* in your program, every function you've written is UB. A clever C++ compiler could replace your entire program with `cout << "Hello world"` and still be conformant to the standard. Basically, compilers are allowed to assume UB doesn't happen and optimize around that use case, so if UB happens, then [ex falso quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) anything is possible.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo UB propagates only if the code path is executed. `if (false) { UB; }` does not cause any bad things to happen. On the other hand, `a(); if (flag) UB;` can legally be converted to `if (flag) { UB; } else a();` because the `UB` propagates backward to prevent `a()` from executing at all if `flag` is true.