# When can static_cast be used safely for downcasting in C++?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, dynamic-cast, downcast, static-cast

I need to know under which conditions `static_cast` can be used in order to convert a parent class pointer to a child class pointer without causing an undefined behavior.

Usually `dynamic_cast` is recommended for safe downcasting, but what if the pointer that originally pointed to a parent class object never uses any member of the child class? Is it safe to use `static_cast` in this case?

If yes, then the following example code should not lead to any undefined behavior.

**Example:**

```
struct Parent {
    int i = 3;
    void print() { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
};
struct Child : Parent {
    double d = 5;
    void change() { i *= 2; }
};

int main() {
    Parent* pParent = new Parent;
    Child* pChild = static_cast<Child*>(pParent);
    pChild->print(); //should be ok
    //std::cout << pChild->d << std::endl; //undefined behavior
    //pChild->change(); //does this lead to an undefined behavior?
}
```

**Bonus question:** Is it safe to use a member function from the child class, if that function only uses members from the parent class? In the example above this would mean the use of

```
pChild->change();
```

**Goal:**
My goal is to avoid `dynamic_cast` in order to safe performance. As long as I know how to avoid an undefined behavior for sure I am willing to take the risk of using `static_cast` instead.
There are already existing threads about downcasting with `static_cast`, but none of them really answers under which conditions an undefined behavior can be avoided.

Comment: A static_cast to a child pointer will be undefined behavior, even if you're only using members of the parent class.

Comment: Relevant standard draft passage: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#12 _"If the prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B” points to a B that is actually a base class subobject of an object of type D, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type D. **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined**."_

Comment: @Brian61354270 I have read that passage before, but I was not sure what exactly it would imply. Let's say I define a conversion from Child to Parent. Is it then ok to use static_cast?

Comment: It says that you get UB immediately on the wrong downcast, no matter what you do with the result. *"Let's say I define a conversion from Child to Parent"* How is it related?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: The quoted passage from Brian says "if no valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists ([conv.ptr]), the program is ill-formed"

Comment: You're reading the wrong sentence, this one just says that casting two unrelated pointers is a compile-time error. Read the last sentence, the one quoted in the comment.

Comment: @cockatiel That passage is talking about [standard conversions](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv) between _pointers_, not between D and B.  "standard conversion from 'pointer to D' to 'pointer to B'" is referring to https://eel.is/c++draft/conv#ptr-3 What that's saying is that if the upcast is ill-formed, then the downcast is also ill-formed.

Comment: If you're looking for ways to avoid dynamic casting, then you can use an `enum` (or similar) for a type, checking that type and `static_cast`ing appropriately. Of course, this would require that you as a programming ensure the validity of the types. Though, the general approach is to avoid needing to down cast.

Comment: One thing that is still making me suspicious is the following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Quote: "static_cast can also cast through inheritance hierarchies. It is unnecessary when casting upwards (towards a base class), but when casting downwards it can be used as long as it doesn't cast through virtual inheritance. " - end quote.

So I guess the one who wrote this answer in the other thread was wrong about that.

Comment: No. It just means casting through virtual inheritance is ill-formed, other downward casts are well-formed but may invoke UB. Please read the sentence right after the one you quoted.

Comment: What about the case when a base pointer that has been originally created from a derived pointer can be cast back to a derived pointer again with static_cast? This is what I have just read in the C++ Primer (written by Stanley Lippman) on page 602. Quote: "when we know that the conversion from base to derived is safe, we can use a
static_cast (§ 4.11.3, p. 162) to override the compiler" - end quote.

Comment: That is of course safe and legal.

Comment: One thing is for sure, casting unrelated types is UB so avoid that one.

Comment: if `Parent* pParent = new Child` the `Child* pChild = static_cast<Child*>(pParent);` will be ok. in your case this wrong by sense, because `pParent` not point to `Child` anyway. *that function only uses members from the parent class* - so move the `void change()` to `Parent`. this is correct solution

Comment: "Goal: My goal is to avoid dynamic_cast in order to safe performance" - Unless you have used a profiler to determine that `dynamic_cast` is actually one of your major performance issues, then I'd say that this is premature optimization and you are unlikely to see any measurable performance benefit.

Comment: This is not only a clear dupe, you're asking multiple questions.

Comment: @jonspaceharper: My main question was in which case ```static_cast``` can be safely used for downcasting. The bonus question of mine had just the goal the dig deeper into the main question. It was not meant to introduce multiple questions.

Comment: The other stack overflow threads about downcasting with ```static_cast``` did not clearly explain the conditions when it can be used safely. So I did not consider my question to be a duplicate. Now I have seen that someone suggested that the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71505316/does-this-downcasting-lead-to-undefined-behavior) already answer my question and I think I can agree with that. However, the title "Does this downcasting lead to undefined behavior?" is not very descriptive and other people may have a hard time finding it as well, if they have the same problem like me.

Comment: You can't do that because you never instantiate a child. pParent is a Parent, not a Child.

Comment: Reading all the comments and the answer is confusing me. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast first item states that down cast if base is virtual is ill-formed while some SO post and comments here seem to say otherwise. In the case of virtual inheritance, could someone give a clear answer (typically by explaining why ```static_cast<D>(B)``` would be ill-formed when B is a virtual base class). Besides what would be the difference with ```static_cast<D*>(B*)```

Comment: `static_cast<D>(B{})` is always ill formed. `static_cast<B>(D{})` slices the object and is usually not what you want. `static_cast<D*>(B*)` is ill-formed if virt. inheritance is involved, UB if the `B*` does not point to part of an actual `D`, well-formed and well-defined otherwise. First item is about reference. Reference basically have the same rule as pointers. So `static_cast<D&>(B&)` follows the same rule as `static_cast<D*>(B*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but what if the pointer that originally pointed to a parent class object never uses any member of the child class? Is it safe to use static_cast in this case?

No, the behavior is still undefined.

> If yes, then the following example code should not lead to any undefined behavior.

The example has undefined behavior because `pParent` points to an object of type `Parent` that is not a base class subobject of some `Child` object, which according to the standard causes causes `static_cast<Child*>(pParent)` to have undefined behavior.

> Bonus question: Is it safe to use a member function from the child class, if that function only uses members from the parent class?

No, the cast itself, even if the result is not used at all, has undefined behavior.

> Goal: My goal is to avoid dynamic_cast in order to safe performance.

You can use `static_cast` safely for downcasts in exactly the same circumstances in which `dynamic_cast` would *not* return a null pointer. In the other cases, the `static_cast` will have undefined behavior. That's precisely *why* `static_cast` is faster.

It is impossible to obtain a pointer to a `Child` if the `Parent` object wasn't created as base class subobject while creating a `Child` object. The language does not permit this at all. To operate on a `Child*` in any way, you need to create a `Child` object first.

Usually it is better to use an appropriate `virtual` function interface instead of `dynamic_cast`. This is both more performant and doesn't violate OOP principles like `dynamic_cast` does.